# Property Data Not Outputing to Controls

Tags: c#, list, methods, controls, output

In one of my current projects, I have been attempting to develop a system that will take data input from textboxes on one form, and input them into a list on another form so that they may be displayed via a listbox and labels on another form as a data reference for manual input into a database.

```
//Create Attendance Report Instance
    AttendanceReport report = new AttendanceReport();

private void inputButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            //Declare Variables
            string administratorVerify = verificationBox.Text;

            //Inputs Change Based on NewStudent Check
            if (passwordInput.Text == passwordTextBox.Text)
            {
                //Save Changes
                Save();
            }
         Relevant Section =>  else if (newStudentCheck.Checked == true)
            {
                //New Verification Instance
                VerificationClass verify = new VerificationClass();

                //Verification Gateway
                if (verify.Verify(administratorVerify) == true)
                {
                    //Send Student to Attendance Report List
                    report.DisplayStudent();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized Password\nOnly Authorized Administrators May Access this Function");
                }
            }

            //Clear Inputs
            clearInputs();
        }
```

I designed the part of the program that retrieves the data and displays it to function off of an universal instance of the second form, calling an instance of the first form to retrieve the data. I originally had the program create a new instance of the second form whenever the input button was clicked, before I moved the instantiation out of that block, making it a universal instance.

```
List<NewStudent> studentList = new List<NewStudent>();

private void RetrieveStudentInfo(NewStudent student)
    {
        //Temp Variables
        int ID;
        int Grade;

        //Create MainForm Instance
        MainForm reference = new MainForm();

        //Get Values
        student.Class = reference.classBox.Text;
        student.Name = reference.nameBox.Text;
        if (int.TryParse(reference.idBox.Text, out ID))
        {
            student.ID = ID;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID");
        }
        student.Password = reference.createPasswordBox.Text;
        student.District = reference.districtBox.Text;
        student.Country = reference.countryBox.Text;
        if (int.TryParse(reference.gradeBox.Text, out Grade))
        {
            student.Grade = Grade;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Grade");
        }
    }

    public void DisplayStudent()
    {
        //Create Object
        NewStudent student = new NewStudent();

        //Get Student Info
        RetrieveStudentInfo(student);

        //Add Object to List
        studentList.Add(student);

        //Add Entry to Selection

        newStudentSelection.Items.Add(student.ID);
    }
private void newStudentSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get Selected Item
        int index = newStudentSelection.SelectedIndex;

        //Display Data
        classOutput.Text = studentList[index].Class;
        nameOutput.Text = studentList[index].Name;
        idOutput.Text = studentList[index].ID.ToString();
        passwordOutput.Text = studentList[index].Password;
        districtOutput.Text = studentList[index].District;
        gradeOutput.Text = studentList[index].Grade.ToString();
        countryOutput.Text = studentList[index].Country;
    }
```

For all my life, from where I stand it seems like this program should work. I Intellisense is giving me no styntax errors, and I have attempted to review my logic with fellow amateur programmers in person, but for what ever reason, the data will not output to the controls on the second form. The only I can think of is that somehow by reference variables I pass as arguments to my `RetrieveStudentInfo` method and such are not actually getting passed somehow, but that shouldn't be correct.
Any advice on this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: VerificationClass, MainForm, NewStudent.  Are these all forms?  If so, you create them, but never show them.  You probably want to pass the existing reference of the form on the screen.

Comment: MainForm is the first form, and AttendanceReport is the second. Verification Class is just a class I'm using for password verification, and NewStudent is where the properties whose values I'm assigning and trying to pass to the AttendanceReport controls come from.

Comment: But you are making a "new" MainForm.  This one isn't the one on the screen.